# Is it possible to force all DateTime properties to be modeled as DateTime2?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, datetime2

In Entity Framework 6 Code First, is there a way to force all `DateTime` properties to be modeled as `DateTime2`?

I know that I can do

```
.HasColumnType("datetime2")
```

on each individual `DateTime` property, but I'm wondering if there's a way to set it as a default for *all* `DateTime` properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

In Entity Framework 6's Fluent API, you can update all `DateTime` properties using this one line:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
```